# Launch MySQL Command Line Client directly within MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is their a way to Launch MySQL Command Line Client directly within MySQL Workbench? Similar to how Visual Studio Code has a terminal pane by the output.

I am trying to setup logging `mysql> tee` and `mysql> notee` commands form MySQL Workbench with ought having to open a separate MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client.

Another example would be running a basic `mysql> help` from MySQL Workbench without having to open a separate MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client.

Comment: Good question, but is there something wrong with just loading up a bash outside of Workbench and using that instead?

Comment: Not at all, just wondering if it was an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The only shell that you can use within Workbench is the Python shell to write plugins or access the internal GRT tree.

Comment: Thanks, that was my thought as well. Just wanted a professional opinion.